# How to handle form in selenium which is coming while scrolling on webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

There is Form coming while scrolling, i need to send search data in that form and click on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Actions` class to scroll down to that item. sample code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of javascriptexecutor to scroll element into view

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```